# Writing ("injecting") text into existing Ubuntu terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, automation

Given the name of an *already running* terminal (`gnome-terminal` maybe?), is there a way to write text into it from another program?

I am basically looking for a way to start compilation from a text editor.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please comment so that we can try to make the answer better.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have them, install `xwininfo`(in package x11-utils) and `xvkbd`:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-utils
sudo apt-get install xvkbd
```

Then find the window id of your "victim" window:

```
xwininfo
```

the cursor become a cross --- click on the gnome-terminal window where you want to inject the text. Among the info, copy the window id:

```
xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
      would like information by clicking the
      mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0x1a005be "romano@samsung-romano: ~"
[...]
```

Now from another terminal you can inject characters:

```
(0)samsung-romano:~% xvkbd -window 0x1a005be -text "ls -l\n"
```

(Remember the `\n` if you want the command executed).

There are more way to identify the window --- look at the [man page of xvkbd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/xvkbd.1.html).
One of the method is to use the "class" property of XWindows. You can run a terminal with a specific class-name of your choice, for example:

```
xterm -class alfa &
```

and then inject in it via

```
xvkbd -window alfa -text "ls -l\n"
```

(I used `xterm` here, I couldn't do that with `gnome-terminal` --- I don't know why).

Comment: This looks good, though I haven't had the chance to try it, which is why I did upvote this answer but have not accepted it. At any rate, I do need an automatic way to identify a gnome-terminal window, so requiring a user to click on a terminal won't do. You did give me a direction, so I can tinker now. Thanks!